# In CruiseControl.NET what is the difference between the XSLs in the server and webdashboard directory

Tags: xslt, cruisecontrol.net

In CruiseControl.NET there appears to be the same xsl stylesheets in the server directory as well as the webdashboard directory?

Is one for transformation for saving to the build report xml and the other for display on the web dashboard?

What are the different directories of xsl stylesheets used for?

-- Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one in the server directory is usually used when sending the build report emails, and the one in the webdashboard directory is obviously for what's displayed in the website.

I actually copy the XSLs that I actually use to a common directory and reference them from both places.